# Flycheck with file relative eslint executable

Tags: flycheck

A lot of projects I work on install eslint as a dev dependency, with a custom set of eslint plugins. Right now, flycheck uses the globally installed version of eslint rather than the version of eslint installed with each project.

I would like to make flycheck point to node_modules/eslint/bin/eslint.js instead. The full path should depend on the path of the current buffer's file so I can be working on multiple projects at the same time with each buffer using a potentially different eslint executable.

Is this possible? Any suggestions for how I would go about doing this?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can programmatically change `flycheck-javascript-eslint-executable`, e.g.

```el
(defun my/use-eslint-from-node-modules ()
  (let* ((root (locate-dominating-file
                (or (buffer-file-name) default-directory)
                "node_modules"))
         (eslint
          (and root
               (expand-file-name "node_modules/.bin/eslint"
                                 root))))
    (when (and eslint (file-executable-p eslint))
      (setq-local flycheck-javascript-eslint-executable eslint))))

(add-hook 'flycheck-mode-hook #'my/use-eslint-from-node-modules)
```

This code looks for a `node_modules` directory in any parent of the buffer's directory and configures Flycheck to use an eslint executable from that directory if any exists.

Comment: I wish my emacs-fu were this good. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: If you have global-flycheck-mode set, then I recommend
`(and eslint (file-executable-p eslint))`

I was encountering errors otherwise trying to, i.e. edit my .emacs file

Comment: Here's what you can do if you need an inline hook (and avoid adding custom functions) : http://emacs-fu.blogspot.in/2008/12/hooks.html

Comment: security note: only open files in trusted folders/projects; you will auto-execute any malicions eslint binary

Comment: I would use the path `"node_modules/.bin/eslint"`, just in case eslint ever changes their directory structure.

Answer (score 4):

I don't have enough reputation to comment on the accepted solution. But I made a variation of it, that works well with nested packages (for example using [lerna](https://github.com/lerna/lerna)). This is the exact same code, however it looks up the parent `node_modules` folder recursively until it finds an `eslint` binary, and uses it. This way, you can have a lerna project have only one eslint configuration, shared between all sub-packages.

```
(defun my/use-eslint-from-node-modules ()
  (let ((root (locate-dominating-file
               (or (buffer-file-name) default-directory)
               (lambda (dir)
                 (let ((eslint (expand-file-name "node_modules/eslint/bin/eslint.js" dir)))
                  (and eslint (file-executable-p eslint)))))))
    (when root
      (let ((eslint (expand-file-name "node_modules/eslint/bin/eslint.js" root)))
        (setq-local flycheck-javascript-eslint-executable eslint)))))
(add-hook 'flycheck-mode-hook #'my/use-eslint-from-node-modules)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm on windows and this wasn't working for me, I think the file-executable-p or perhaps the flycheck internals were failing to locate the correct file. As when its working it is pointing to the `.cmd` file and not the `.js` file.

I found a comment in [flycheck-eslint does not use version of eslint installed in JavaScript project](https://github.com/flycheck/flycheck/issues/1087#issuecomment-246783846) and their [blog post](https://www.simplify.ba/articles/2016/02/14/node-modules-bin-in-path/) to use [directory variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Directory-Variables.html) instead.

In the root directory of the project create a file `.dir-locals.el`

```
((nil . ((eval . (progn
                   (add-to-list 'exec-path (concat (locate-dominating-file default-directory ".dir-locals.el") "node_modules/.bin/")))))))
```

Now when I visit the javascript file `flycheck-verify-setup` correctly finds the file `<dir>/node_modules/.bin/eslint.cmd`

Answer (score 0):

My previous solution was a pain to get working across different projects.

I've modified the accepted answer to hard code windows stupidities.

```
(defun my/use-eslint-from-node-modules ()
  (let* ((root (locate-dominating-file
                (or (buffer-file-name) default-directory)
                "node_modules"))
         (eslint (and root
                      (expand-file-name "node_modules/.bin/eslint.cmd"
                                        root))))
    (when (and eslint (file-exists-p eslint))
      (setq-local flycheck-javascript-eslint-executable eslint))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that combines [Bae's](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/31356/) and [lunaryorn's](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/21207/) answers using a `dir-locals.el` file in the root directory of the project (or, more specifically, in the directory that contains the `node_modules/` folder where the `eslint` binary lives). Create said `dir-locals.el` file with the following content.

```
((js2-mode
   (flycheck-checker . javascript-eslint)
   (eval . (setq-local flycheck-javascript-eslint-executable
             (concat (locate-dominating-file default-directory
                       ".dir-locals.el") "node_modules/.bin/eslint")))))
```

Here I'm assuming you are using the `js2-mode` emacs major mode to edit javascript files. If that's not the case, change that line accordingly.
The second line of the file makes the `javascript-eslint` syntax checker the only one to be used within this project.
The third line sets the variable `flycheck-javascript-eslint-executable` to `<root-dir>/node_modules/.bin/eslint`.
In this way we don't modify emacs' `exec-path`.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried a few different variations of this and never found exactly what I wanted.  I've finally leveled up enough in Emacs lisp to modify it to my liking.  What my version does is look for a local eslint and if one is not found it falls back to a globally installed one:

```
(defun configure-web-mode-flycheck-checkers ()
    ;; See if there is a node_modules directory
    (let* ((root (locate-dominating-file
                  (or (buffer-file-name) default-directory)
                  "node_modules"))
           (eslint (or (and root
                            ;; Try the locally installed eslint
                            (expand-file-name "node_modules/eslint/bin/eslint.js" root))

                       ;; Try the global installed eslint
                       (concat (string-trim (shell-command-to-string "npm config get prefix")) "/bin/eslint"))))

      (when (and eslint (file-executable-p eslint))
        (setq-local flycheck-javascript-eslint-executable eslint)))

    (if eslint
        (flycheck-select-checker 'javascript-eslint)))
```